InvalidArgumentException Disk [minio] does not have a configured driver
when i try to connect to minio errro like this 
i am using laravel and try to connect to minio . i just try to insert key and secrate key directly filesystem.php when i try to connect to minio there  is error like this sometime there is show
** InvalidArgumentException  Disk [minio] does not have a configured driver.**

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
